# Как улучшить код подключения к БД и установления Роли?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, инспекция-кода

Я подключаюсь к БД и провожу запрос и установление Роли. Мне не нравится как громозко это выглядит, и яб хотел как то это улучшить, но я не знаю как...

```cs
public partial class Login : Form
    {
        private int x = 0;
        private int y = 0;
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        int i;
        string status1;
        string status2;
        string status3;


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkedRadioButton();
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    string loginUSER = textBox1.Text;
                    string passUSER = textBox2.Text;
                    DB database = new DB();

                    DataTable table = new DataTable();

                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

                    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `authorized` WHERE `Login` = @uL AND `Password` = @uP AND `Status`= @uR", database.getCon());
                    command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUSER;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUSER;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@uR", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status1;

                    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    adapter.Fill(table);

                    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Вы вошли!");
                        Form f = new MainForm(i);
                        f.Show();
                        Hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Проверьте корректность введенных данных");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    string loginUSER1 = textBox1.Text;
                    string passUSER1 = textBox2.Text;

                    DB database1 = new DB();

                    DataTable table1 = new DataTable();

                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new MySqlDataAdapter();

                    MySqlCommand command1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `authorized` WHERE `Login` = @uL AND `Password` = @uP AND `Status`= @uR", database1.getCon());
                    command1.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUSER1;
                    command1.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUSER1;
                    command1.Parameters.Add("@uR", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status2;

                    adapter1.SelectCommand = command1;
                    adapter1.Fill(table1);

                    if (table1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Вы вошли!");
                        Form f = new MainForm(i);
                        f.Show();
                        Hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Проверьте корректность введенных данных");
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    string loginUSER2 = textBox1.Text;
                    string passUSER2 = textBox2.Text;

                    DB database2 = new DB();

                    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();

                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new MySqlDataAdapter();

                    MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `authorized` WHERE `Login` = @uL AND `Password` = @uP AND `Status`= @uR", database2.getCon());
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUSER2;
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUSER2;
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@uR", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status3;

                    adapter2.SelectCommand = command2;
                    adapter2.Fill(table2);

                    if (table2.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Вы вошли!");
                        Form f = new MainForm(i);
                        f.Show();
                        Hide();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Проверьте корректность введенных данных");
                    }
                    break;

                   
            }
        }
        private void checkedRadioButton()
        {
            if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                i = 1;
                status1 = "Администратор";

            }
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                i = 2;
                status2 = "Мастер";
            }
            if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
            {
                i = 3;
                status3 = "Клиент";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста метод, создающий и изменяющий пользователя в базе. Есть замечание, которое с ним связано. Ревью напишу чуть позже.

Comment: @aepot, не совсем понял. Вообще там только root роль, а все остальное записано в таблицу ,отдельную.. То есть запросы идут через таблицу и соответственно проверка только с ней, возможно можно как то это исправить,хм

Comment: Ок, напишу на основе того что вижу.

Comment: Для использования каких-ли перечислений (администратор, мастер, клиент) используйте enum. Это гораздо удобнее. Если через некоторое время вы взгляните на ваш код, поймёте, что не помните, что это за i. Таким образом, исчезнет нужда в status1, status2 status3 -> все эти 4 поля можно объединить в один enum

Comment: Благодаря этому исчезнет необходимость всех этих лишних switch-case

Comment: @Frehzy совет хороший, но старайтесь не предлагать compile-time структуры данных для runtime данных. Это сильно усложняет дальнейшее развитие проекта. Хардкод того что может поменяться - нехорошо. Проще утащить в базу значения какого-нибудь словарика, чем перечисления, так же?

Comment: Абсолютно согласен с вами. Я б хранил какие-либо роли в отдельной таблице со своими гуидами, сохранял их в словарь (roleid, roleName). В таблице пользователей тогда-бы было login, password, roleId. Это позволило-бы максимально гибко работать с кодом и дополнять его, но такое вряд-ли подойдет, тк придется частично переписывать структуру программы и бд автора

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, зачем вы создали класс `DB`? В последнее время всё чаще вижу аналогичные никчёмные бесполезные классы, которые оборачивают соединение. Это в каких-то учебных заведениях так учат? Или какой-то обучающий курс или видео стал популярен, где так сделано? / Удалите этот класс. Вместо него используйте напрямую `MySqlConnection`, при этом обязательно используйте `using`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov преподаватели учат, но при этом они не объясняют, что всю работу с базой лучше туда уносить, или плохо объясняют.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По порядку. Сначала вычищаю то что есть не меняя логики, затем даю советы по исправлениям.

Это вообще зачем здесь?

```cs
private int x = 0;
private int y = 0;
```

Удаляем.

Совершенно непонятно, что это и для чего это

```cs
int i;
string status1;
string status2;
string status3;
```

Называйте переменные более понятными именами. Почему 3 статуса? Ведь далее по логике видно, что хватит одного.

Далее идет вызов метода `checkedRadioButton` где видно, что каждый из этих статусов используется однократно. Тогда зачем их три? Давайте так.

```cs
private int role;
private string roleName;
```

Так, стоп, а зачем они вообще? :) Ведь их можно не хранить в форме, а возвращать из метода. Но  2 значения из метода возвращать не очень удобно, почему бы не создать массив, он прекрасно ложится на логику.

```cs
private readonly string[] roleNames = new[] { "Администратор", "Мастер", "Клиент" };
```

Единственное расхождение, это у вас нумерация ролей начинается с единицы, а у массива индексы начинаются с нуля.

Тогда метод `СheckedRadioButton`, кстати, называйте методы с большой буквы, будет выглядеть так.

```cs
private int СheckedRadioButton()
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
        return 1;
    if (radioButton2.Checked)
        return 2;
    if (radioButton3.Checked)
        return 3;
    return 0;
}
```

И напишу вспомогательный метод

```cs
private string GetRoleName(int role)
{
    return roleNames[role - 1];
}
```

Далее, запрос в базу. Вам же не нужны данные из таблицы, а нужно только посчитать количество строк в ней по данному запрос, ну так давайте считать.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `authorized` WHERE `Login` = @uL AND `Password` = @uP AND `Status`= @uR
```

И результат запроса можно получить вот так

```cs
long rowsCount = (long)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Ничего лишнего.

Далее, вы не диспозите `IDisposable` объекты, это не очень хорошо.

```cs
using(MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("...", database.getCon())
{
    // здесь работа с командой
}
```

Почитайте: [Использование объектов, реализующих IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).

Далее, вы вызываете `Hide();`, а когда главная форма будет закрыта, кто закроет форму логина? В результате ваше приложение никогда не завершится. Придется использовать костыли типа `Application.Exit()` и прочие. Подпишитесь на событие закрытия формы и закрывайте форму логина вместе с ней.

```cs
f.FormClosed += (s, e) => Close();
```

Если вдруг захочется при закрытии главной формы показать форму логина, просто `Close` замените на `Show`. Всё, теперь можно из главной формы выходить просто ее закрывая через `Close()`.

Итого получилось вот так:

```cs
public partial class Login : Form
{
    private readonly string[] roleNames = new[] { "Администратор", "Мастер", "Клиент" };

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int role = СheckedRadioButton();
        string loginUSER = textBox1.Text;
        string passUSER = textBox2.Text;
        DB database = new DB();

        long rowsCount = 0;
        try
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `authorized` WHERE `Login` = @uL AND `Password` = @uP AND `Status`= @uR", database.getCon()))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUSER;
                command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUSER;
                command.Parameters.Add("@uR", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GetRoleName(role);
                rowsCount = (long)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException) { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        if (rowsCount > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Вы вошли!");
            Form f = new MainForm(role);
            f.FormClosed += (s, e) => Close();
            f.Show();
            Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Проверьте корректность введенных данных");
        }
    }

    private string GetRoleName(int role)
    {
        return roleNames[role - 1];
    }

    private int СheckedRadioButton()
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
            return 1;
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
            return 2;
        if (radioButton3.Checked)
            return 3;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Повторяющийся код - индикатор того что что-то пошло не так, избегайте повторяющегося кода.

---

Теперь замечания по общей логике:

1. **Никогда не храните в базе данных пароли в открытом виде**, используйте хэширование, любое, например SHA256. Если база данных попадет в руки злодея, он по хэшам не сможет узнать оригинальные пароли.
2. Почему роли у вас захардкожены? Заведите в базе таблицу `roles` с полями `id, access_level, name` и запрашивайте `SELECT access_level, name FROM roles` и не придется держать массив. К тому же, если у вас новая роль появится, вы будете форму логина перепиливать, а потом еще 10 местах код приложения изменять? Позже научитесь делать `JOIN` и вам еще больше понравится наличие отдельной таблицы с ролями.

Добавьте больше гибкости, закладывайте то, что может случиться в архитектуру заранее. Меньше хардкода, меньше сввязей между компонентами приложения - больше гибкости в разработке.

Кстати, я бы убрал `radioButton` и получал бы роль из базы, примерно так.

```sql
SELECT Status FROM `authorized` WHERE `Login` = @uL AND `Password` = @uP
```

Пусть база данных определяет роль, а не пользователь.

Comment: Отличный ответ. Почти все мои мысли выразили. Конечно, можно добавить различных НО. Например, почему весь код написан на View? Может стоит добавить сервер для общения с бд и создать на нём кэш, с которым клиент будет взаимодействовать? И ещё несколько придирок, связанных со слабой способностью кода к доработкам.

Comment: @Frehzy я исходил из того, чтобы автору не пришлось переписывать ничего в других частях приложения при замене кода.

Comment: @aepot огромное спасибо за информацию, буду теперь все переделывать :D Но единственной выводит ошибку с Null значением .-. в строчке, где идет ExecuteScalar() : System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: @aepot, int rowsCount = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: @Eliz вы точно правильно скопировали код? Это при неуспешной авторизации происходит или всегда? В запросе `COUNT(*)` не забыли поправить?

Comment: @aepot всегда, видимо что то не так с принятым значением

Comment: @Eliz понял, исправил код, оно просто если строк нет `DBNull` возвращает, а его нельзя привести к `int`.

Comment: @Eliz если вас пугает `??` то можете переписать вот так `if (command.ExecuteScalar() is int count) { rowsCount = count; }`

Comment: @aepot, да всеб ничего если бы ошибка исчезла, ладно попробую выводить не через ExecuteScalar

Comment: @Eliz я отредактировал ответ, посмотрите изменения, исправил уже эту ошибку, обновите страницу. `ExecuteScalar()` прекрасно работает.

Comment: @aepot, ну видимо не в моем варианте. Я вставлял исправления - оно в любом случае ругается.

Comment: @Eliz покажите текущий код, например через https://pastebin.com/, дайте посмотрю.

Comment: @aepot https://pastebin.com/X3tvGCbx

Comment: @Eliz добавил `try-catch`, обработка ошибок здесь оказалась надежнее.

Comment: @aepot он игнорирует `try-catch` ) Добавил `database.openCon();` и `close.Con();` Теперь ругается на некорректность данных. Буду искать.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо огромное за обратную связь! в итоге: помогло это - `rowsCount = (Int64)command.ExecuteScalar();`

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем коде нарушен принцип DRY ([читайте здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself))

Вы можете написать вот так:

```
public partial class Login
{
    private int x = 0;
    private int y = 0;

    private string _status;

    public Login()
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkedRadioButton();

        string loginUSER = textBox1.Text;
        string passUSER = textBox2.Text;
        DB database = new DB();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `authorized` WHERE `Login` = @uL AND `Password` = @uP AND `Status`= @uR", database.getCon());
        command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUSER;
        command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUSER;
        command.Parameters.Add("@uR", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _status;

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Вы вошли!");
            Form f = new MainForm(i);
            f.Show();
            Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Проверьте корректность введенных данных");
        }
    }
    private void checkedRadioButton()
    {
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            _status = "Администратор";
        }
        if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            _status = "Мастер";
        }
        if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
        {
            _status = "Клиент";
        }
    }
//...
```

И пожалуйста, посмотрите Code Convension по названию переменных и методов в C#

Comment: `new MainForm(i)` не скомпилится, будьте внимательнее

Comment: @aepot я не вникал в суть кода, просто подкоректировал грубые нарушения. Ваш ответ более полный и правильный

Comment: Почитайте описание метки `инспекция-кода`, когда она есть - надо вникать в суть и писать код-ревью, если возможно.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!