# Как вывести данные авторизированного пользователя в разные label?

Tags: c#, sql-server, авторизация

После авторизации выводится фамилия,имя пользователя или никней и всё это в один lebel,а как сделать так чтобы например фамилия в label1, а имя в label2?

```
    try
            {
                DataSet set = new DataSet();
                set = DataBaseSource.DataBaseCreator("select Nickname,Password,RoleID,Surname,Name from Users");
                for (int i = 0; i < set.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (txtNickname.Text == set.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() && txtPassword.Text == set.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString())
                    {
                        switch (set.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString())
                        {
                            case "1": MainClient client = new MainClient("1", set.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()); client.Show(); this.Hide(); break;
                            case "2": MainAdmin admin = new MainAdmin("2", set.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString()+" "+ set.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString()); admin.Show(); this.Hide(); break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Это Winforms?..

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1412851/373567