# Никак не могу разобраться с кодом с#

Tags: c#, sql

Помогите вывести MessageBox с ошибкой при одинаковом вводе логина. Уточняю пользователь регистрируется вводит логин и пароль, при одинаковом логине выводится ошибка повторяющееся значение ключа.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SelectPassword = $"Insert Into Пользователи values ('{textBox2.Text}','{textBox3.Text}')";
        connectDB.command = new SqlCommand(SelectPassword, connectDB.ConnectionDB);
        try
        {
            connectDB.ConnectionDB.Open();
            connectDB.command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connectDB.ConnectionDB.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!");
            this.Hide();
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
            frm1.Show();
        }
        catch (SqlException exception)
        {
            if (exception.Number == 1003)
                MessageBox.Show("Измените свой логин!");
                connectDB.ConnectionDB.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1412851/373567 Попробуйте ещё раз объяснить, что именно с этим кодом не так.

Comment: Странная логика. Старайтесь в программирование доводить свое приложение до ошибок только в крайних случаях. Что вот например вам мешает отправить в базу запрос на поиск данного логина? Вам база без ошибок даст результат, и если такое найдено, выдаете сообщение, если нет, регистрируете. Вот ради любопытства, погуглите, что значит ошибка `1003`, всегда, и на всех базах она будет давать нужный вам результат? Думаю нет. И да, когда вы опускаете скобки, и пишете что-то по типу `if (...) ...`, то только следующая строка будет задействована в этом `if`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, можно ли присвоить переменной значение столбца логина, и уже в коде проверять есть ли повторяющийся логин, если моя логика верна, помогите пожалуйста это сделать

Comment: Что сделать? Отправить запрос на получение данных из базы? я думаю вы без труда это сделаете самостоятельно.