# Почему метод всегда возвращает true

Tags: c#, sqlite

Есть метод для проверки табельного номера в базе данных. Предполагается, что если он возвращает true, то новый сотрудник не создается. Если такого табельного номера нет, то возвращается false и в базе создается новый сотрудник.

```
private bool CheckPersonnelNumber()
{
    SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand();
    command = DataBase.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
    DataBase.OpenConnection();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT PersonnelNumber FROM Employees WHERE PersonnelNumber = @PersonnelNumber";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonnelNumber", createEmployeePersonnelNumberBox.Text);
    bool answer = Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteNonQuery());
    DataBase.CloseConnection();
 
    return answer;
}
```

Почему метод всегда возвращает true?

Comment: А что реально возвращает `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`, вы проверяли? Что делает `Convert.ToBoolean` с таким значением? Этот вопрос решается банальной отладкой. И я бы делал `SELECT COUNT(PersonnelNumber)` и `command.ExecuteScalar()` а дальше смотрел в возвращаемое число. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1412851/373567

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.